# When to call next() in node.js when using Firebase to fetch data

Tags: node.js, express, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

There is probably an easy solution to my problem, but I cannot seem to wrap my head around the problem.

The problem is: I am using node.js with the express.js framework for an app I am creating. I am also using Firebase.js as my database. I am starting to understand middleware and how we can use that to fetch data, before sending the response to the client.

My problem is however, that if I want to loop through child nodes in Firebase, I would want to use their datasnap.forEach() like so:

```
var scoresRef = db.ref("scores");
    scoresRef.orderByValue().on("value", function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
    console.log("The " + data.key + " dinosaur's score is " + data.val());
  });
});
```

So lets say I have a module which should get all the dinosaurs value, I could do this:

```
var dinoModule = {};
dinoModule.getDinosaurs = function(req, res, next){
    var dinoRef = firebase.database().ref("dinosaurs");
    dinoRef.orderByValue().on('value', function(snapshot){
        snapshot.forEach(function(data){
          // do something with the data here
          // Calling next() here is wrong 
       });
      // Should I call next() here?
    });
}
```

But where should I call the next function so that the server does not halt?

Answer (score -1):

Do you know about promises in nodejs?
You need to use promises here to solve your problem.

```
var async = require('async');
var dinoModule = {};
dinoModule.getDinosaurs = function(req, res, next){
    var dinoRef = firebase.database().ref("dinosaurs");
    dinoRef.orderByValue().on('value', function(snapshot){
        async.eachSeries(snapshot,fucntion(data,callback){
          //call the callback() here after success
          //in case of errors call callback(err) where err is error object
        },function(err){
            if(err){
             //this will be called in case of error
            }else{
             //this will be called for success after interation over
             //call next() here
            }
          })
    });
}
```

Comment: Your answer is a bit unclear... Yes, promises could solve this problem, but... your example code doesn't use any promises.

Comment: we are using async here which also gives blocking in code and hence serves the purpose.